# Recyclerview, problema ao inserir um item

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-intent

Fala galera, sou novo no android, tô com um probleminha aqui, estou tentando inserir itens em um Recyclerview, quando uso o método direto no botão ele tá inserindo estaticamente de boa:

```
public void listenersButtons() {

                floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         // Cria uma nova pessoa

                        ModelContato pessoa1 = new ModelContato();
                        pessoa1.setNome("Felipe");

                        //Adiciona a pessoa1 e avisa o adapter que o conteúdo
                        //da lista foi alterado

                        pessoasListas.add(pessoa1);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Mas agora preciso evoluir, quero que quando clique nesse mesmo botão abra uma tela com um formulário e um botão de salvar, lá eu capturo os dados e jogo de volta para a main.

Tô fazendo assim:

```
public void listenersButtons() {

            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   Intent it = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, Contato.class);
                   startActivity(it);
                   finish();

                }
            });
        }
```

E de lá retorna as Strings e eu tô tentando inserir no Recyclerview assim:

```
@Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();

            Intent itt = getIntent();

            if (itt != null){
                Bundle parametro = itt.getExtras();


                if (parametro != null){

                    ModelContato pessoa1 = new ModelContato();

                    if (parametro.getString("nome") != pessoa1.getNome()) {

                        String nome = parametro.getString("nome");
                        String email = parametro.getString("email");
                        String num = parametro.getString("num");

                        pessoa1.setNome(nome);
                        pessoa1.setEmail(email);
                        pessoa1.setNumero(num);

                        pessoasListas.add(pessoa1);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

O problema é que agora quando retorno ele preenche o recycleview corretamente com os valores que preenchi no form, só que ao fazer o processo novamente ele substitui, ou seja, fica sempre apenas 1 item em minha lista.

Eu coloquei dentro do onResume por tentativa e erro, testei também no onCreate e acontece a mesma coisa.

Outro detalhe é que ao navegar pela aplicação, quando vou em outra activity e volto para a principal um novo item é adicionado, igual ao anterior, tentei corrigir isso com o ultimo if do cod no onResume, mas não funcionou.

Não da erro algum, mas não funciona como preciso.

Agradeço desde já, vlw!

Answer (score 1):

O RecyclerView nao persiste (salva) os dados que voce manda pra ele, quando voce abre outra activity, eles se perdem.

Voce precisa utilizar um banco de dados (SQLite é o mais facil no Android) pra salvar os dados do formulario, e utilizar esse mesmo banco pra popular o RecyclerView na activity que voce mostra ele.

De uma olhada nesse tutorial (em ingles): http://androidheight.blogspot.com.br/2015/11/sqlite-database-in-android-application.html

E nesse aqui em portugues: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-crud-com-android-studio-e-sqlite/32815

Espero que tenha ficado claro o que esta acontecendo, qualquer duvida deixa um comentario que eu tento te explicar ;)

Comment: Obrigado pelo material.

Answer (score 0):

Você deverá usar o método startActivityForResult ao invés de startActivity
Dentro do onActivityResult, você programa para receber um objeto do tipo ModelContato e adiciona na lista que está dentro do adapter. Por fim, dá um notifyDataSetChanged no adapter.

Na main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 999) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                atualizaMeuAdapter((ModelContato)data.getSerializableExtra("novoUser"));
            }
        } 
    }
```

No Click do botão para ir para a tela de add contato

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
```

Quando voce salva o usuario na tela de add contato:

```
public void salvar(){
    usuario.salvar();

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("novoUser", usuario);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Lembrando que a entidade do usuário tem que implementar Serializable. É esse o modo mais fácil eu acredito.